# Meaning of "drop" in SpaCy custom NER model training?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

Below code is an example training loop for SpaCy's named entity recognition(`NER`).

```
for itn in range(100):
    random.shuffle(train_data)
    for raw_text, entity_offsets in train_data:
        doc = nlp.make_doc(raw_text)
        gold = GoldParse(doc, entities=entity_offsets)
        nlp.update([doc], [gold], drop=0.5, sgd=optimizer)
nlp.to_disk("/model")
```

`drop`  as per `spacy` is the drop out rate. Can somebody explain the meaning of the same in detail?

Comment: randomly dropping features/internal representation  to avoid overfitting.This makes it harder for the model to memorize the training data.

Comment: Does it mean, if there are 100 records that needs to be trained, and i give drop as 0.5, then in the first epoch only 50 records will be used for training?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the documentation [here](https://spacy.io/api/entityrecognizer), the SpaCy `Entity Recognizer` is a neural network that should implement the **thinc.neural.Model** API. The `drop` argument that you are talking about is something called [dropout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropout_(neural_networks)) rate which is a way to optimize a neural network.

The recommended value is `0.2` based on my experience which means that about 20% of the neurons used in this model will be dropped randomly during training.